# Can I pull data from Journey Builder with SQL?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder, sql

I am looking to write a query to pull people who did not meet entry criteria in Journey Builder. Or is there a report to pull?

If you can write a query, what other data views can I pull from journey builder?

Answer (score 2):

No. None of this information is exposed through API or data view.

Comment: Is this still a valid answer?

Comment: Partially, yes. There's still no data view or extract type to do this, but there is an undocumented and unsupported REST endpoint you can use. https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/27/get-journey-history-by-filtering-the-definition-id-via-api/. It's fraught with challenges, if you're looking to get data out in bulk as you can't sort results and can only get out 10K batches of events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can pull Journey Builder data.
Please check:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey.htm&type=5

Comment: Do not post link-only answers, please.  Can you add the relevant content from the link in the answer here and give the reference to the link. Thanks!